# How to access variable of the parent class from a DexClassLoader?

Tags: android

I have an application that run a method from a class via DexClassLoader like that :

```
Class<?> classToLoad = new DexClassLoader(codeFile.getAbsolutePath(), tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).loadClass("com.payload.mypayload.Payload");

classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("run", new Class[0]).invoke(classToLoad, new Object[0]);
```

So it run the "run" method from the Payload class and I would like to access the attributes of the class that calls my payload from the code of the "run" method.

I tried a lot of things but I can't find how to access attributes/methods of the class that calls it..

Do you have an idea of how should I do that ?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *access* attributes/methods? You sure you're not mixing up *class* and *object*?

Comment: I want to access the value of a "variable" of the class that calls my dex payload.

Comment: `class` is a type. It's the `object` which is the instance that holds the data. So you create the object with `new Class[0]`, and then you need something like `klass.getField("name").get(obj)`. All this said, I'm not sure you'll get what you expect, it's a freshly created object.